# jQuery - how to add new name to cloned select

Tags: jquery, select, input, clone

Hi i've got a problem with code:

I wat to ad new name values to newly created selects, maybe i'll show

This is jQuery javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#plus').click(function() {
            //variables for input
            var num     = $('.inputCopy').length;
            var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);

            var newInput = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);


            newInput.children(':first').attr('id', 'input' + newNum).attr('class','next' + num);

            $('#input' + num).after(newInput);
            $('#del').css({display: ''});

            //if 5 inputs hide add input
            if (newNum == 5)
                $('#add').css({display: 'none'});
        });
.....
    });
```

and this is HTML:

```
<div class="box0">
 <ul>
   <li>Set of selects to clone</li>
   <li>
    <ul>
     <li></li>
     <li>Select 1</li>
     <li>Select 2</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li id="input1" class="inputCopy">
    <ul class="some">
      <li class="selects">Selects set &new value&</li>
      <li>
        <select name="Select[Ask][&new value&][Adults]" id="parent">
          <option label="1" value="1">1</option>
          <option label="2" value="2">2</option>
          <option label="3" value="3">3</option>
          <option label="4" value="4">4</option>
        </select>
       </li>
       <li>
        <select name="Select[Try][&new value&][Children]" id="children">
         <option label="0" value="0">0</option>
         <option label="1" value="1">1</option>
         <option label="2" value="2">2</option>
         <option label="3" value="3">3</option>
         <option label="4" value="4">4</option>
        </select>
      </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
    <li class="pnav" id="minus"><a href="javascript:void(0);" >delete</a></li>
<li class="pnav" id="plus"><a href="javascript:void(0);" >add selects</a>   </li>
</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

My problem is that those two selects have names and i want to put the new values only in place where i wrote **&new value&** how can i do that only for newly created select.

if new set of selects put 1 etc.

i've hope that my problem is easy to solve but i can't find solution

Comment: So, when the user selects one option, the name should be updated by replacing "/***new value***/ with the value of the option?

Comment: no no when user click link "add selects" the new selects names will be `Select[Try][1][Adults]` and `Select[Try][1][Children]` if add another selects `Select[Try][2][Adults]` and `Select[Try][2][Children]` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the script a bit, and I believe I've found a solution (if I did understand your questions correctly). In the HTML, I replaced "/***new value***/" with "1", making it:

```
<select name="Select[Ask][1][Adults]" id="parent">
```

For the script, I added a counter ("nextSelectValue"), which will hold the value that is to be inserted. After the clone of the element is done, it finds the select-element and replaces the number using a regex-expression. As this is just the "plus"-side, you'll have to update the "nextSelectValue"-variable accordingly for the "delete"-side. Here is the script:

```
// Variable for keeping track of what number is next
var nextSelectValue = 2;
var newInput;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#plus').click(function() {

      //variables for input
      var num     = $('.inputCopy').length;
      var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);

      // Clone select and update id
      newInput = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

      // Update "new value" and variable "nextSelectValue"
      var selectInput = newInput.find('select');
      selectInput.attr('name', selectInput.attr('name').replace(/\d+/, new String(nextSelectValue)));
      nextSelectValue += 1;

      newInput.children(':first').attr('id', 'pokoj' + newNum).attr('class','next' + num);

      $('#input' + num).after(newInput);
      $('#del').css({display: ''});

      //if 5 inputs hide add input
      if (newNum == 5)
          $('#add').css({display: 'none'});
    });
});
```

Let me know if you have any problems with it.

**EDIT:** If you are using a name with two integers, instead of this:

```
selectInput.attr('name', selectInput.attr('name').replace(/\d+/, new String(nextSelectValue)));
```

use this

```
selectInput.attr('name', selectInput.attr('name').replace(/\d(?=[^\d]*\d)/, new String(nextSelectValue)));
```

But be aware, this will ONLY work if it's exactly two numbers in the string

Comment: Oh man you are awesome this works prefectly. Thank you so much :)

Comment: hi, i've got only one question how can i change only the first numer in name cause if i clone element that name looks like `Select[Ask][1][Adults][1]` the cloned element looks `Select[Ask][2][Adults][0]` it should be `Select[Ask][2][Adults][1]`

Comment: Hey! Sorry for my late response, I've been otherwise occupied. I'll post a solution later to today, a bit busy atm :P

Comment: Will the first brackets always contain 'Ask'? And are you planning to extend the name further?

Comment: yes it'll always contain 'Ask' and `Select[Ask][2][Adults][1]` is a full name and only change will be numbers in name